# How to put multiple ads on android app?

Tags: android

Hi I have checked the internet and admob's site to see if it is possible to ad multiple ads to an android app.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

It's just a view so it should be possible.  Have you tried it?  Are you getting an error?